# Checkbox seleccionado en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy buscando que los checkbox de SQL Server estén preseleccionados según el dato contenido adentro y no he podido realizarlo. He intentado de todo, acá el último código que he ejecutado.

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="hongosbacterias">8. Hongos/Bacterias/Virus: </label>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                            <?php
                                $conn = connectDB();
                                $sql = "select honBacVir from formulario";
                                $result = query($conn, $sql);
                                while ($arreglo = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    for($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++){
                                    $sel = "";
                                    if ($_POST['hongosbacterias'] == $arreglo['honBacVir']) $sel = "checked";
                                    ?>
                                   <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="hongosbacterias[]" value="Esclerotinia" <?= $sel ?>>
                                        Esclerotinia
                                      </label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="hongosbacterias[]" value="Fusarium" <?= $sel ?>>
                                        Fusarium
                                      </label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="hongosbacterias[]" value="Mildiu" <?= $sel ?>>
                                        Mildiu
                                      </label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="hongosbacterias[]" value="Botritis" <?= $sel ?>>
                                        Botritis
                                      </label>
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="hongosbacterias[]" value="otros" <?= $sel ?>>
                                        Otros
                                      </label>
                                <?php }
                                }
                                 ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Y así están guardándose en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando PHP normal.

Comment: SI puedes coloca el form en el que envías los datos por POST, o comprueba si te esta llegando los datos en $_POST['hongosbacterias'], puede ser que ahí te este dando FALSE.

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿deberían seleccionarse dos checkbox en la primera línea de la tabla de la base de datos? , por cierto, estás usando funciones que ya no existen en PHP7, deberías tener en cuenta esto y utilizar las más recientes.

Comment: Como dice Shaz, tendrías que verificar los datos que vienen en $_POST['hongosbacterias'].
Si están correctos verifica también lo que trae $arreglo['honBacVir'].
Cuéntanos como te fue.